# What is the <id> in Group Conversations

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

What is the  parameter and how can I get it? I need to get my conversations.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups//conversations

Answer (score 0):

It's an id of the group that you want to access the conversations of. 
You can get the list of groups you're a member of with a https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf request. Note though that only unified groups can have conversations. The following request will get you a list of unified groups that you're a member of: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a%20eq%20%27unified%27)